# link to Twitter profile with only a Twitter name - RoR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, hyperlink

I have user's Twitter names and want to add links from their profiles to their Twitter accounts.

I've been trying to concatenate `@Profiles.twitter` (their twitter name) to the end of a plain twitter.com hyperlink, but with no luck.

Currently I have it just showing the names in text, but want them to be links

```
<p>
  <strong>Twitter:</strong>
  <%= @profile.twitter %>
</p>
```

you can view the result here: http://warm-hollows-1154.herokuapp.com/profiles/4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example:

```
<% @name = "pierre" %>
<%= link_to @name, "http://www.twitter.com/" + @name %>
```

Try this

```
<%= link_to "LINK", "http://www.twitter.com/" + @profile.twitter[1..-1] %>
```

**Edit:**

[1..-1] removes the @ sign

You don't need to create @name, i just used it as an example, you alreade have a string @profile.twitter. Just use this below

```
<%= link_to @profile.twitter, "http://www.twitter.com/" + @profile.twitter[1..-1] %>
```

Comment: so that works, but when I try to do `@name = @profile.twitter` or `<%= link_to @profile.twitter, "http://www.twitter.com/" + @profile.twitter %>` no luck. What am I missing here?